# Laravel : How to get image array in controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I want to pass an array in postman in which there is a image field.
But I am not getting it in to controller.
How Can I do it ?
I am passing the value like as below image.

[image]
In Header :[image]

In my controller :

```
 if($request->get('documentObject'))
        {
      foreach ($request->get('documentObject') as $documentDetails) {
                    if(Input::file($documentDetails['documentimage']))
                    {  // i am not getting it 
                    }
```

How can I get it?

Comment: you can change your request GET to POST and use foreach in controller like foreach ($request->documentObject as $documentDetails) { }

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your form markup contains `enctype multipart/form-data`. Otherwise, `file` will be null.

For troubleshooting, you could also dump out the contends of the request to see what the browser is sending: `dd($request->all())`.

Comment: It is showing `Undefined index: documentimage-`.In `Header` it is set `Content-Type` - `multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent`

Comment: After looking at the code/request again, `$documentDetails` is going to be your key. Try changing your loop to `$request->get('documentObject')  as $key => $documentDetails`